# File generated by servlet not downloading

Tags: java, html, post, attachment, content-disposition

I have a servlet with an action that generates a CSV file based on parameters passed in a POST from a form. The servlet code snippet looks like this:

```
response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + filename);
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
pw.println(content); // content is some CSV in a string
pw.close();
```

The browser (both FF and Chrome) appears to be ignoring the attachment indicator, because it changes URL to the corresponding action (e.g. http://myserver.com/filedownload) and does not present a Save As dialog. I've checked the response header in Chrome, and it looks like this (edited to now show the full, "unparsed" header):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=JobTracking.csv
Content-Type: text/csv;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 16876
Date: Tue, 15 Jul 2014 22:32:49 GMT
```

..and the "Response" tab shows the content I'm writing to the response.

I'm close to my wits end, because fairly much all the examples I've looked at do it this way successfully.

Comment: Please post the full response the browser is receiving. Maybe there's a redirect happening?

Comment: By "full response", do you mean what is in the "Response" tab in the Chrome developer tools window? That just has the CSV being written to the response. I've edited the question to show the "unparsed" response header.

Comment: What is the request URI, and what do you mean by "corresponding action"?

Comment: Action meaning what the action property is in the form, e.g <form id="myform" action="../filedownload" method="POST">, so the request URI ends up being, for example: http://myserver.com/filedownload. I've since set up a test harness using another, individual page which is separate from the app (it's a combination of JSP/jQuery Mobile), and that works, so it seems to be affected by the page structure somehow. Seriously beats me why, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery mobile, forms are handled by Ajax by default, using data-ajax="false" solved the issue, e.g.

```
<form id="myform" action="../filedownload" method="POST" data-ajax="false">
```

Bit of a head-slapping moment, there :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have content type and encoding swapped in your example. It should be

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Not sure how you getting back `Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8` in the response though.

**Edit:**

Also, the correct MIME type for CSV files is `text/csv` and not `application/vnd.ms-excel` - this one is for `*.xls` files.

Comment: I replaced what were constants with the actual values, for readability sake. Unfortunately, I swapped them around; edited question is now correct. Changing to text/csv makes no difference, nor does application/x-unknown, or just about anything else.

Comment: @DaveNottage Please post the complete response along with all the headers like Julian Reschke suggested